# Firebase push notification error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have integrated firebase push notification and followed all the procedure correctly, firstly by creating project in firebase and creating certificate and added the p12 file to firebase project. The code is fine but when i run the app on real device it shows me this in console,

```
" You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled) "
```

When i send any message from firebase and select my app from there and click send button in the place of an app it shows me unknown app name as u can see in screenshot. I'm confused that where i'm doing mistake no error is coming. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on your project in Xcode then on Capabilities then turn on Push Notifications.

Comment: i had on it but still not working. @AaqibHussain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add (ON) the capabilities pf push notification for your app / project 
[image]

also check  for UIbackground capabilities

[image]

Error message is talking about this ignore selected blue item search for your best match 
[image]

Comment: bro i have done it but it isn't sending any message and as in screenshot its written unknown app , i think so our app bundle id should show there if we r sending message. @M Faheem Rajput

Comment: Then create your app (on firebase) again with correct bundle identifier

Comment: the bundle identifier is correct bro. @M Faheem Rajput

Comment: do you have real device for testing notifications ?

Comment: yup and when i run the app it isn't ask permission for firebase notification. @M Faheem Rajput

Comment: i have added my info.plist screen shot check it is it correct? @M Faheem Rajput