# Can't Find FCM Data when app is in Background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am working with FCM in iOS development. I have successfully integrated firebase push notification service. It works for both foreground and background properly but i need the push data which is sent from firebase console. when the app is in Foreground, i can get all data perfectly but when app is in background, i can't get the data. can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making GCM work for iOS device in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31109514/2754146).

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662976/firebase-push-notification-error-in-ios/46663088?noredirect=1#comment80275076_46663088

Comment: i have added "content_available": 1 in the JSON payload, and now it works. Thanks everyone!